# Postback on a textbox within an update frame using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I have an asp.net page that contains a gridview within an update panel. On this Gridview there is a number of Textboxes. One of these textboxes causes a postback when it loses focus (textChanged event) and the updatepanel does a postback. I want this textboxes only to do a postback if there are 20 characters in it when it loses focus. I have written a javascript function to do this but I still have a problem. When I do the postback the whole page reloads, not only the update panel. I had something like the below function, can anyone explain how I can get it to only postback the update panel:

```
<script language='Javascript'>
     function CheckPostback(var textbox)
     {
        if(textbox.value.length() == 20)
        {
            __doPostBack(textbox.Id, '');
        }
     }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `__doPostBack` with the Id of the UpdatePanel you want to do the partial postback on should be a better bet. See [Easily refresh an updatepanel using javascript](http://encosia.com/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/) for more information.

This question [ASP.NET: Manually updating an UpdatePanel using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460288/asp-net-manually-updating-an-updatepanel-using-jquery) should be useful as well.